# JQuery Mobile swipe between Pages like a gallery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

My App consists of different HTML5 Pages. I know how to swipe between them with JQuery Mobile. But I want something like a horizontal progress bar. So that the users knows that there a maybe 10 pages and he is a the beginning.

I know these gallery plugins. But I don't want to swipe images. I want to swipe the whole pages without any buttons.

I'll hope someone has an idea how to code something like that or has an example project for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/

I have implemented a jquery mobile swipe before, but it wasn't that smooth though. If your page is doing a post back it won't be that good. I'd recommend trying out this link. Very smooth transitions.

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/07/building-a-touch-friendly-html5-site/
Example code is included.

This will be difficult on jQuery mobile. I would include this sample code inside of one jquery mobile page.

Answer (score 2):

That would be easy to achieve if you use the native transition function as follow:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
   $.mobile.changePage( "target-page.html", {      
       transition: "slide", 
       reverse: false, 
       changeHash: false,
       reloadPage: true      
   });
 });
```